# Trouble with saving data to and reading from a file in c

Tags: c, file

As per the heading really the code for saving the data to a file seems to work fine as the program runs and the file exists.
However in the second part of code the program compiles but stops with error when running.
Before I post code wanted to say thanks to the posters as I have learned a lot from this site but is my first time posting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int const MAX_SIZE = 1000000;
FILE *randomdata;
char outputFilename[] = "array.dat"; 

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    randomdata = fopen(outputFilename, "w");  
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        fprintf(randomdata, "%lf\n", rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen the first piece of code makes a file called array.dat which stores random numbers.

The second piece where I assume there is a logic error somewhere is meant to take in the numbers from array.dat and then figure out the median value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000000

#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int left, right;
    int pivot_index, store_index;
    int i, k;
    double tmp;
    double a[MAX_SIZE];
    double pivot_value;
    double start;
    double end;

    FILE *f;
    char inputFilename[] = "array.dat";

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        f = fopen("array.dat", "r");
        fscanf(f,"%lf", &a[i]);
        printf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }

    k = MAX_SIZE / 2; /* the median position */
    left = 0; right = MAX_SIZE;
    start = clock();
    srand(time(0));

    while (left != k) {
        pivot_index = rand() % (right -left) + left;
        pivot_value = a[pivot_index]; /* swap (a[ pivot_index ],a[ right -1]) ; */
        tmp = a[pivot_index];
        a[pivot_index] = a[right - 1];
        a[right - 1] = tmp;
        store_index = left;

        for (i = left; i < right - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] < pivot_value) { /* swap (a[ store_index ], a[i ]) ; */
                tmp = a[store_index];
                a[store_index] = a[i];
                a[i] = tmp;
                store_index++;
            }
        } /* swap (a[ right -1] , a[ store_index ]) ; */

        tmp = a[right - 1];
        a[right - 1] = a[store_index];
        a[store_index] = tmp;
        pivot_index = store_index;

        if (k <= pivot_index) {
            right = pivot_index;
        } else {
            left = pivot_index + 1;
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    printf("The program took %lf seconds\n", endstart / 1000000);
    printf("Median is %lf\n", a[k - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem in the code definitely comes somewhere around the following part I think:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
    f = fopen("array.dat", "r");
    fscanf(f,"%lf", &a[i]);
    printf ("%lf", &a[i]);
}
```

Comment: First error in your code, you do no error checking whatsoever. So don't expect your code to work. If you don't check that `fopen()` returned a non-`NULL` pointer you risk invoking Undefined Behavior, so you can't rely on the result of your program.

Comment: `f = fopen("array.dat", "r");` - that does **not** belong *inside* the loader loop. It should appear above the loop. You're surely running out of file descriptors, and leaking `FILE*`'s like crazy.

Comment: You need to include the actual error message in your question.  In general it's also a good idea to format your code to improve the readability.

Comment: Things to do to help solving this yourself: 1. Indent your code properly (using some code formatting tool if possible). 2.Turn on compiler warnings, and fix any warnings you get. 3. Check return values of IO functions for errors.  Once these basic things are in order, then it is time to start trying to figure out why your program does not work right.

Comment: Following @iharob it is essential to check the function return value of the  `scanf` family too, and any other functions which involve external data. You are at its mercy if there is anything unexpected. Quite often in the real world, there will be, either by accident or by malicious intent.

Comment: There is no fixed error, just runtime.exe has been forced to stop when I run it. I'm sorry about poor formatting also, it is an assignment I have to do but we have had no teaching to do with file usage at all so I have just been trying to link the two programs together without any real knowledge of what is actually happening. I will do some research now on file check errors and implement them.

Answer (score -1):

there are three things you must know about while using FILE in read mode in c .
1) open the file first by fopen();
2) check whether the file is open or not.
3)close the file by fclose().